# Pusher: How to bind to 100s of events?

Tags: pusher

The push library works as below

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('test_channel');
channel.bind('my_event', function(data) {
  alert(data.message);
});
```

However:
Would I be able to do this?

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('test_channel');
channel.bind(['my_event1', 'my_event2'....'my_event100'], function(data) {
  alert(data.message);
});
```

In my use case, I have one channel and there are many different events and each client might want to simulantaneously subscribe to 100s of events.

Answer (score 5):

The signature for the `channel.bind` function is `String channelName, Function callback` ([pusher-js source](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js/blob/master/src/events_dispatcher.js#L13)). You can't pass in an `Array` of channels`.

If you want the same function to be called then you'll need to pass a reference to the function and call `bind` multiple times:

```
var channel = pusher.subscribe('test_channel');
var callback = function(data) {
  alert(data.message);
};

var eventName;
for( var i = 0; i < 100; ++i ) {
  eventName = 'my_event' + ( i + 1 );
  channel.bind( eventName, callback );
}
```

The single-threaded nature of JS will equate to these event binding happening simultaneously.

You could of course create your own helper function to allow `bind( Array eventNames, Function callback )`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Would binding to hundreds of events have a performance cost?

Comment: It would be a tight `for` loop. However, it doesn't result in any IO of any kind. 100s should be fine.