# Listen to Multiple Events on a Pusher Channel

Tags: pusher

I'm trying to listen on a single channel to multiple events using Pusher.js.

I thought you had to separate the event names by a space, but that doesn't seem to be working.  I've tried comma limited and also passing an array of strings.

```
channel.bind(
"open_auction close_auction"
"open_auction, close_auction"
"['open_auction', 'close_auction']"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only bind to a single event so you'd either need to manually define each listener or store an array of events and loop through them (creating a new listener each time). Check out the answer here for more information: [Pusher: How to bind to 100s of events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20892778/pusher-how-to-bind-to-100s-of-events?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably outdated, but pusher has a channel.bind_global that would allow you to listen to all events sent to that channel. Docs: https://pusher.com/docs/channels/using_channels/events/#example-3